# The most NextFlow-like (DSL2) way to incorporate a former bash scheduler submission script to a NextFlow workflow

Tags: groovy, nextflow

New to `NextFlow`, here, and struggling with some basic concepts. I'm in the process of converting a set of `bash` scripts from [a previous publication](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-019-1707-2) into a `NextFlow` workflow.

I'm converting [a simple bash script](https://github.com/mebbert/Dark_and_Camouflaged_genes/blob/master/scripts/08_COMBINE_AND_GENOTYPE_ADSP/submit_combine_and_genotype.ogs) (included below for convenience) that did some basic prep work and submitted a new job to the cluster scheduler for each iteration.

**Ultimate question**: What is the most NextFlow-like way to incorporate this script into a NextFlow workflow (preferably using the new DSL2 schema)?

**Possible subquestion**: Is it possible to emit a list of lists based on `bash` variables? I've seen ways to pass lists from workflows *into* processes, but not *out of* process.  I could print each set of parameters to a file and then emit that file, but that doesn't seem very NextFlow-like.

I would really appreciate any guidance on how to incorporate the following `bash` script into a NextFlow workflow. I have added comments and indicate the four variables that I need to emit as a set of parameters.

Thanks!

```
# Input variables. I know how to take these in.
GVCF_DIR=$1
GATK_bed=$2
RESULT_DIR=$3
CAMO_MASK_REF_PREFIX=$4
GATK_JAR=$5

# For each directory
for dir in ${GVCF_DIR}/*
do
    # Do some some basic prep work defining
    # variables and setting up results directory
    ploidy=$(basename $dir)
    repeat=$((${ploidy##*_} / 2))
    result_dir="${RESULT_DIR}/genotyped_by_region/${ploidy}"  # Needs to be emitted
    mkdir -p $result_dir

    # Create a new file with a list of files. This file
    # will be used as input to the downstream NextFlow process
    gvcf_list="${ploidy}.gvcfs.list"                          # Needs to be emitted
    find $dir -name "*.g.vcf" > $gvcf_list 

    REF="${CAMO_MASK_REF_PREFIX}.${ploidy}.fa"                # Needs to be emitted

    # For each line in the $GATK_bed file where 
    # column 5 == repeat (defined above), submit
    # a new job to the scheduler with that region.
    awk "\$5 == $repeat {print \$1\":\"\$2\"-\"\$3}" $GATK_bed | \
        while read region                                     # Needs to be emitted
        do 
            qsub combine_and_genotype.ogs \
                    $gvcf_list \
                    $region \
                    $result_dir \
                    $REF \
                    $GATK_JAR
        done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the most NextFlow-like way to incorporate this script into a
> NextFlow workflow

In some cases, it is possible to incorporate [third-party scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts) that do not need to be compiled "as-is" by making them executable and moving them into a folder called 'bin' in the root directory of your project repository. Nextflow automatically adds this folder to the $PATH in the execution environment.

However, some scripts do not lend themselves for inclusion in this manner. This is especially the case if the objective is to produce a portable and reproducible workflow, which is how I interpret "the most Nextflow-like way". The objective ultimately becomes how run each process step in isolation. Given your example, below is my take on this:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.GVCF_DIRECTORY = './path/to/directories'
params.GATK_BED_FILE = './path/to/file.bed'
params.CAMO_MASK_REF_PREFIX = 'someprefix'

params.publish_dir = './results'
```

```
process combine_and_genotype {

    publishDir "${params.publish_dir}/${dirname}"

    container 'quay.io/biocontainers/gatk4:4.2.4.1--hdfd78af_0'

    cpus 1
    memory 40.GB

    input:
    tuple val(dirname), val(region_string), path(ref_fasta), path(gvcf_files)

    output:
    tuple val(dirname), val(region_string), path("full_cohort.combined.${region}.g.vcf")

    script:
    region = region_string.replaceAll(':', '_')

    def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga() : 0

    def Xmx = avail_mem >= 8 ? "-Xmx${avail_mem - 1}G" : ''
    def Xms = avail_mem >= 8 ? "-Xms${avail_mem.intdiv(2)}G" : ''

    """
    cat << __EOF__ > "${dirname}.gvcf.list"
    ${gvcf_files.join('\n'+' '*4)}
    __EOF__

    gatk \\
        --java-options "${Xmx} ${Xms} -XX:+UseSerialGC" \\
        CombineGVCFs \\
        -R "${ref_fasta}" \\
        -L "${region_string}" \\
        -O "full_cohort.combined.${region}.g.vcf" \\
        -V "${dirname}.gvcf.list"

    gatk \\
        --java-options "${Xmx} ${Xms} -XX:+UseSerialGC" \\
        GenotypeGVCFs \\
        -R "${ref_fasta}" \\
        -L "${region_string}" \\
        -O "full_cohort.combined.${region}.vcf" \\
        -V "full_cohort.combined.${region}.g.vcf" \\
        -A GenotypeSummaries
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    GVCF_DIRECTORY = file( params.GVCF_DIRECTORY )
    GATK_BED_FILE = file( params.GATK_BED_FILE )

    Channel.fromPath( params.GATK_BED_FILE ) \
        | splitCsv(sep: '\t') \
        | map { row ->
            tuple( row[4].toInteger(), "${row[0]}:${row[1]}-${row[2]}" )
        } \
        | set { regions }

    Channel.fromPath( "${GVCF_DIRECTORY.toString()}/**/*.g.vcf" ) \
        | map { tuple( GVCF_DIRECTORY.relativize(it).subpath(0,1).name, it ) } \
        | groupTuple() \
        | map { dirname, gvcf_files ->
            def ploidy = dirname.replaceFirst(/^.*_/, "").toInteger()
            def repeat = ploidy.intdiv(2)

            def ref_fasta = file( "${params.CAMO_MASK_REF_PREFIX}.${dirname}.fa" )

            tuple( repeat, dirname, ref_fasta, gvcf_files )
        } \
        | combine( regions, by: 0 ) \
        | map { repeat, dirname, ref_fasta, gvcf_files, region ->
            tuple( dirname, region, ref_fasta, gvcf_files )
        } \
        | combine_and_genotype
}
```

From the GATK docs, I couldn't actually see where the variant inputs could be a list of files. Maybe this feature was only available using an older GATK. The code above is untested.

Also, you will need to ensure your code is indented using four spaces. The above will throw some error if tab indentation is used, or if you were to indent using a different number of spaces.

Comment: Hello @Steve, this is super helpful. I'm hung up on a small issue. I actually emit `GVCF_DIRECTORY` as a `path` from a previous process. I cannot figure out how to extract the path as a string to concatenate it to `/**/*.g.vcf`. I think everything that's emitted is emitted through a `Channel`. So, how do I get access to that underlying `path` object to call `getName()`?

Comment: Regarding: "I couldn't actually see where the variant inputs could be a list of files", turns out this feature is not well documented in `GATK`. You can pass in a `<file_name>.list` (with `.list` extension) in various scenarios. See https://www.biostars.org/p/9501554/ and https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us/articles/360041416312-MergeVcfs-Picard-

Comment: @MarkEbbert Sorry I may have missed that note above. I think you might be able to simplify things considerably if, instead of just emitting the whole `GVCF_DIRECTORY`, you output something like: `path "./some/path/**/*.g.vcf", emit: gvcf_files` and `path "./some/path/**/*.fa", emit: fasta_files`. Then [filter](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#filter) the fasta_files channel for files that start with your CAMO_MASK_REF_PREFIX and, after grouping the gVCF files channel, [join](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) the two channels using each file's parent name.

Comment: @MarkEbbert This is a design decision, but you might instead prefer a single output declaration like: `path "some/path/**"`. This creates an output channel of all files, recursively (rather than just the top level directory name), which can be grouped and filtered (like above) to get the 'combine_and_genotype' inputs. Happy to show how this could work if you could update your question with some of these details. Some example output filenames in this directory would also help, if possible. Thanks also for letting me know about magic .list extension! That is a nice feature indeed.

Comment: Thanks @Steve! Your suggestion to emit the following worked: `path "./some/path/**/*.g.vcf", emit: gvcf_files`. I did not emit the `.fa` files bc they're generated once and not by the previous process. I learned that emitting `path "./some/path/**/*.g.vcf", emit: gvcf_files` does NOT behave the same as `Channel.fromPath( "${GVCF_DIRECTORY.toString()}/**/*.g.vcf" )`. I had to `flatten()` the emitted paths. I also made a small change to the next line, resulting in: `PREVIOUS_PROC.out.camo_gvcfs.flatten().map { tuple( it.subpath(it.getNameCount() - 2, it.getNameCount() - 1).name, it )}`